# How to integrate my Android app with SL4A?

Tags: android, android-intent, integration, sl4a

I want to integrate my app with SL4A. In order to let the user to do something in reponse to events in my app i'd like to send intents with data to SL4A or just execute sl4a script in the file using filename.

How can this be done?

EDIT: i don't want to use sl4a source code in my app.

Comment: I need to integrate a script in my app. Have you found something in the while?

Answer (score 0):

There are functions to work with intends in SL4A scripts. If this is what you are looking for?

http://www.mithril.com.au/android/doc/AndroidFacade.html

Comment: This seems to be Android interface available in SL4A and is used to perform action by SL4A in Android. I'd like to send intents **TO** SL4A from my Android app in order to provide actions support on events in my app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install sl4A and corresponding interpreter on the device.